# Error in Closing Connection in C# access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

```
      private void FoodList_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  {

         try  {
                **Connections.con.Open();**

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = Connections.con;
                string foodcon = "SELECT ID, FoodName FROM FoodList";
                cmd.CommandText = foodcon;
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(reader["FoodName"].ToString());
                }


        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + err);

        }
        **Connections.con.Close();**
```

The problem is already closed the connection below the code but when I Login there is an error telling me that the connection is still open? any suggestions?

Comment: Using a singleton connection is a bad idea.

Comment: what do you mean singleton connection?

Comment: Having a single static connection.

Comment: what should i do with the connection? how can i use a non single static connection?

Comment: You should create a new connection every time you need one, and use the `using` statement.

Comment: but the Connection.con.Open() came from an another class library so i can call the connection every time i want to use the connection... is used the Connection as a constructor

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, you should be creating the connection object when you create the command object.  You should be doing like this:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("..."))
using (var command = new OleDbCommand("...", connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: class Connections
    {        public static OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..//NewEmployees.accdb");

       
    }

Comment: i have that one on another form... so i could call it anytime?? do i still have to use using?

Comment: @JoeyEguna Yes, you should place the db connection code within a using statement to assure the connection is closed and disposed of when not needed.

Comment: Using an ADO.NET connection created in one form in another form is not good design.  Having your data access properly separated from your forms is a good thing but if you're not going to do that then put all the data access code together.  Having a single connection object offers nothing because ADO.NET is designed for connections to be created and destroyed locally.